# How to rewrite the following code to make it more testable?

Tags: c++, testing, refactoring

This is for programming homework. I am suppose to rewrite the code to make it more testable, but I have no idea what's wrong with it.

```
class Widget {
    private:
        static Toggle toggle;
        Gear gear;
    public:
        Widget();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this way that you wanna write a test for your constructor and your private values/object, what you wanna do is testing a constructor of your class to see when you call it, you will return an instance of a same class? 
How about adding a method to give you an access to those private variable/objects? becuase you won't be able to access private values while you are writing a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's your homework, I am not going to give the solution to you. Rather, I will help you to find a solution.

There are two problems that I can spot - 1) static variable 2)Tight coupling (with Gear). Testing this Widget class is difficult due to both of these problems.

For a detailed understanding, you may watch this (or similar) video - [OO design for testability](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acjvKJiOvXw).